# If a controls datasource has 0 items does it still databind and is there any performance gain by not calling databind if the count is 0?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

I'm curious about this in the case that I have a repeater that I want to hide if there are 0 items.  As far as performance goes should I be doing this:

```
if (data.Count > 0)
{
  rpt.DataSource = data;
  rpt.DataBind();
  rpt.Visible = true;
}
else
{
  rpt.Visible = false;
}
```

or is it fine to just do this:

```
rpt.DataSource = data;
rpt.DataBind();
rpt.Visible = data.Count() > 0;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does a databind, but doens't show anything. For example, if you have a datagrid, and try to bind somme data with empty  datasource, it will not display anything, unless you have set EmptyDataText property of the datagrid to some text. In this case, it will display this text

Comment: There is a header/footer template in the repeater though.  It should build a table if there is data but if not I don't want to render only the table tags

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can bind with empty datasource. As long as DataSource is not null, you can bind it to your control.